# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' even if it is installed (vs code)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-urls, virtual-environment

I have install django in my virtual environment also activated virtual environment but still it is showing these error
python

```
from django.urls import path
```

output

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS E:\django\project\telusko> & C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe e:/django/project/telusko/calc/urls.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\django\project\telusko\calc\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
PS E:\django\project\telusko>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the **pip freeze** command in the activated environment. It django is not present in the result use the following command

```
python -m pip install Django
```

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the `django` in the virtual environment, but you are using the global python environment:

```
C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
```